# Objection variable number of columns in a model

Tags: javascript, knex.js, objection.js

Well say I have a model from a database schema. However this schema itself might be variable, apart from the `id` and `key` columns the number of columns might change/grow over time, I do not know the name of the columns beforehand. (Yes I realize this is not a correct way to design a database, but it's what we have right now).

```
export class PersonModel extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return "person"
    }

    static get idColumn() {
        return "id";
    }

    static get keyColumn() {
        return "key";
    }

    //And some variable number of other columns.

}
```

How would i describe this for `Objection` models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the class into a function to define its properties. This is an example passing just the tablename:

```
export dynamicModelFactory = ({tableName}) => {

  class DynamicModel extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return tableName
    }

    static get idColumn() {
        return "id";
    }

    static get keyColumn() {
        return "key";
    }

    //And some variable number of other columns.
  }

  return DynamicModel
}

const PersonModel = dynamicModelFactory({tableName: 'person'}) // Getting the Objection dynamic model for person tablename
```